# Test Server HTTP 1.1 Compression

Tags: java, http-compression

I want to find about the HTTP 1.1 compression of the site I am talking to.
I need to do it programmatically in Java.

What I want to find out is:
Does the server support compression for incoming requests?
Does the server support compression for responses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a general case answer for this.  The HTTP/1.1 spec lets the client tell the server that it accepts compressed responses, but from the response you can't tell a difference from a server that can't compress responses and a server that just decided not to compress your single response.

Comment: Hmm. And I cannot "force" the server to give me compressed data? Like saying "hey, I only accept gzip and nothing else!" and then see if I get compressed data or an error-code.

Comment: Client's can send an "accept" header that says they support GZip or deflate compression, but it's always assumed that they support non-compressed data as well.

Comment: OK. I'll try that. And how do I evaluate if the actual response was compressed? Evaluate Content-Encoding?